# In this tic tac toe game, why the last move of last player to play, is not showed?

Tags: javascript, html, css

in this tic tac toe game, why the last move of last player to play, is not showed? So, when it's the last turn of the game, nothing is shown on the square, not an O and neither an X. What is the problem?

The code follows:

This is the HTML code:

```
<div id="tictactoe" align="center"></div>
        <div align="center">
            <span id='turn'>Turn of Player X</span>
        </div>
```

This is the CSS code:

```
table {
    border-collapse:collapse;
}

td {
    background-color: black;
    border: 3px solid white;
    font-size:60px;
    color:#ffffff;
    border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
}
```

And this is the JavaScript code:

```
    var N_SIZE = 3,
        EMPTY = "&nbsp;",
        boxes = [],
        turn = "X",
        score,
        moves;

    /*
     * Initializes the Tic Tac Toe board and starts the game.
     */
    function init() {
        var board = document.createElement('table');
    board.setAttribute("border", 1);
    board.setAttribute("cellspacing", 0);
    
        var identifier = 1;
        for (var i = 0; i < N_SIZE; i++) {
            var row = document.createElement('tr');
            board.appendChild(row);
            for (var j = 0; j < N_SIZE; j++) {
        var cell = document.createElement('td');
        cell.setAttribute('height', 50);
        cell.setAttribute('width', 50);
        cell.setAttribute('align', 'center');
        cell.setAttribute('valign', 'center');
                cell.classList.add('col' + j,'row' + i);
                if (i == j) {
                    cell.classList.add('diagonal0');
                }
                if (j == N_SIZE - i - 1) {
                    cell.classList.add('diagonal1');
                }
                cell.identifier = identifier;
                cell.addEventListener("click", set);
                row.appendChild(cell);
                boxes.push(cell);
                identifier += identifier;
            }
        }

        document.getElementById("tictactoe").appendChild(board);
        startNewGame();
    }

    /*
     * New game
     */
    function startNewGame() {
        score = {
            "X": 0,
            "O": 0
        };
        moves = 0;
        turn = "X";
        boxes.forEach(function (square) {
            square.innerHTML = EMPTY;
        });
    }

    /*
     * Check if a win or not
     */
    function win(clicked) {
        // Get all cell classes
        var memberOf = clicked.className.split(/\s+/);
        for (var i = 0; i < memberOf.length; i++) {
            var testClass = '.' + memberOf[i];
      var items = contains('#tictactoe ' + testClass, turn);
            // winning condition: turn == N_SIZE
            if (items.length == N_SIZE) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

function contains(selector, text) {
  var elements = document.querySelectorAll(selector);
  return [].filter.call(elements, function(element){
    return RegExp(text).test(element.textContent);
  });
}

    /*
     * Sets clicked square and also updates the turn.
     */
    function set() {
        if (this.innerHTML !== EMPTY) {
            return;
        }
        this.innerHTML = turn;
        moves += 1;
        score[turn] += this.identifier;
        if (win(this)) {
            alert('Winner: Player ' + turn);
            startNewGame();
        } else if (moves === N_SIZE * N_SIZE) {
            alert("Draw");
            startNewGame();
        } else {
            turn = turn === "X" ? "O" : "X";
            document.getElementById('turn').textContent = 'Turn of Player ' + turn;
        }
    }

    init();
```

This is the link: https://codepen.io/sp2012/pen/gOmXqOO

Thank you.

Comment: It seems to work fine for me. I am using the latest version of Firefox. What exactly does not work for you?

Comment: When the game is about to finish and only one square is left empty and you click on it, the mark is not drawn on the square. And then the program shows you the winner in a alert box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are checking if the player has won the rerender is not happening immediately. When the alert pops up the executiuon is stopped and right after you click OK new game is started. You can use a little hack with setTimeout to show the alert after the rerender has happened

```
if (win(this)) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      alert('Winner: Player ' + turn);
      startNewGame();
    }, 0);
} else if (moves === N_SIZE * N_SIZE) {
    setTimeout(function() {
       alert("Draw");
       startNewGame();
    }, 0);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a timeout in set() before you start a new game:
`setTimeout(...,0)`

Maybe take a look at this:

```js
var N_SIZE = 3,
  EMPTY = "&nbsp;",
  boxes = [],
  turn = "X",
  score,
  moves;

/*
 * Initializes the Tic Tac Toe board and starts the game.
 */
function init() {
  var board = document.createElement('table');
  board.setAttribute("border", 1);
  board.setAttribute("cellspacing", 0);

  var identifier = 1;
  for (var i = 0; i < N_SIZE; i++) {
    var row = document.createElement('tr');
    board.appendChild(row);
    for (var j = 0; j < N_SIZE; j++) {
      var cell = document.createElement('td');
      cell.setAttribute('height', 50);
      cell.setAttribute('width', 50);
      cell.setAttribute('align', 'center');
      cell.setAttribute('valign', 'center');
      cell.classList.add('col' + j, 'row' + i);
      if (i == j) {
        cell.classList.add('diagonal0');
      }
      if (j == N_SIZE - i - 1) {
        cell.classList.add('diagonal1');
      }
      cell.identifier = identifier;
      cell.addEventListener("click", set);
      row.appendChild(cell);
      boxes.push(cell);
      identifier += identifier;
    }
  }

  document.getElementById("tictactoe").appendChild(board);
  startNewGame();
}

/*
 * New game
 */
function startNewGame() {
  score = {
    "X": 0,
    "O": 0
  };
  moves = 0;
  turn = "X";
  boxes.forEach(function(square) {
    square.innerHTML = EMPTY;
  });
}

/*
 * Check if a win or not
 */
function win(clicked) {
  // Get all cell classes
  var memberOf = clicked.className.split(/\s+/);
  for (var i = 0; i < memberOf.length; i++) {
    var testClass = '.' + memberOf[i];
    var items = contains('#tictactoe ' + testClass, turn);
    // winning condition: turn == N_SIZE
    if (items.length == N_SIZE) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}

function contains(selector, text) {
  var elements = document.querySelectorAll(selector);
  return [].filter.call(elements, function(element) {
    return RegExp(text).test(element.textContent);
  });
}

/*
 * Sets clicked square and also updates the turn.
 */
function set() {
  if (this.innerHTML !== EMPTY) {
    return;
  }
  this.innerHTML = turn;
  moves += 1;
  score[turn] += this.identifier;
  if (win(this)) {
    setTimeout(()=>{
      if (confirm('Winner: Player ' + turn))
        startNewGame();
    }, 0)
  } else if (moves === N_SIZE * N_SIZE) {
    setTimeout(()=>{
      if (confirm('Winner: Player ' + turn))
        startNewGame();
    }, 0)
  } else {
    turn = turn === "X" ? "O" : "X";
    document.getElementById('turn').textContent = 'Turn of Player ' + turn;
  }
}

init();
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td {
  background-color: black;
  border: 3px solid white;
  font-size: 60px;
  color: #ffffff;
  border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="tictactoe" align="center"></div>
<div align="center">
  <span id='turn'>Turn of Player X</span>
</div>
```